# Laravel logging race condition?

Tags: php, laravel

It came to my attention recently that a bug didn't always result in an error going to the Laravel log, despite everything else about it being 100% repeatable. It's a simple undefined offset issue, and I've reduced the code down to the below for testing:

```
$x = array();
$y = $x[1];
```

The above code is processed on any of four identical worker queues (`php artisan queue:work --tries=1 --timeout=120 --memory=512`), and the majority of the time results in the below written to laravel.log:

`[2022-02-21 14:34:41] behat.INFO: Undefined offset: 1`

But occasionally, it goes to the queue's stderror log instead, actually in a more useful format, as it happens:

`PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/app/file.php on line 123`

It goes to either one log or the other, never to both. Very ballpark let's say it goes to the Laravel log 80% of the time, with no per-queue pattern observed.

I know from having fixed the underlying bug that both the above errors are generated from the same culprit line of code.

I'll just have to ask that you trust me as to the wider code and test scenario, but it's simple and repeatable, promise.

It's a bog standard single stack log setup:

```
    'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['single'],
        ],

        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],
```

I should add that other logging always makes it to laravel.log, it's just PHP errors that sometimes seem to fall into this hole.

Has anybody seen this before? Or have any pointers as to what's best to check? There's a huge amount of boilerplate code around logging and I don't much fancy spending days or weeks trying to pick this apart, truth be told.

Comment: Have you checked your nginx/apache error logs?  there might be something wrong with writing logs.

Comment: @Debuqer, no, all that's in the Nginx logs is a single line corresponding to the inbound API request, and this is the same for requests that result in either log being written to.

Comment: Can you produce the bug personally? is it possible for logs/laravel.log to be busy most of the time so you cant write on it? can you test this with puting your logs to another channel temporary

Comment: @Debuqer, I'm currently reproducing this on an otherwise completely idle container in a local virtual machine. I've spent a few hours digging through Laravel queue/logging code, not sure I can really justify investing more time in it to be honest. Looks to me as though error can potentially be caught in two places, and one isn't forwarding to the other. Project is also still using Laravel 5.6, which could be part of problem.